# Not able to deploy my app with new changes in heroku

Tags: heroku, codeship

I am the only one who is working in my app , I am trying to deploy app in heroku  through codeship . I am getting the below error, could anyone please help me on this?.

Error :

Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.19.85.154' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
**To git@heroku.com:myApp.git
! [rejected]        f4c7f487a24b4109ee81c242ee78c6659beaf6a4 -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myApp.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.****strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is usually caused by pushing commits to Heroku from a source outside of Codeship.

If those commits are not (yet) included in the tree that triggers a build on Codeship (e.g. because you didn't push them to the remote repository yet, or because they were created during the build on the build VM itself), the push will fail because the remote on Heroku contains commits that would be removed.

One possible (though destructive) solution would be to force push. But be advised that this will likely cause you to loose modifications that were available on Heroku.

If you only ever push to Heroku via Codeship, this shouldn't happen.

If you have more questions or want us to take a look at your build logs, please feel free to open a ticket on https://helpdesk.codeship.com